# React's getDOMNode always return component's root DOM node instead of reffed one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to use *refs* in React. They always return root DOM node of the component instead of reffed one.

Please consider the following example:

```
  var AuthApp = React.createClass({
    onSubmitClick: function(event) {
      var usernameInput = this.getDOMNode(this.refs.username);

      // This logs root <div> instead of <input>, why???
      console.log(usernameInput); 
    },


    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" ref="username"/>
          <input type="password" ref="password"/>
          <input type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmitClick} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

I've inspected the code in excellent Chrome React addon, and it seems that `this.refs.username` properly reflects `<input>` tag:

[image: screenshot of React/Chrome inspector]

Something wrong happens when I call `this.getDOMNode` - it returns root `<div>` specified in `render()` instead of `<input>`.

This code comes from React 0.12, but I've tried to do the same on 0.13 (I am aware of change to `React.findDOMNode()`) and I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Others here have given you the correct answer, I'd just like to add that `this.getDOMNode()` in a component does not take any arguments. Which is why you always get the components DOM node back, regardless of what you pass to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `this.refs['username'].getDOMNode()`. But maybe in newer versions of React you better use `React.findDOMNode`, as adeneo adviced.

Comment: +1, This properly explains the problem; `this.getDOMNode()` takes no arguments and returns the DOM node for the element it's called on, which is why you always get the root node.

Comment: Why didn't I find `getDOMNode` myself. I tried using `ref`on a `<div>` but I kept getting the React component instead of the DOM node. Now I got what I need.

Comment: `.getDOMNode()` has [been deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html). `.findDOMNode` has been moved in to React DOM so should be `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using

```
var usernameInput = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.username);
```

to get a reference to the component's DOM node using `refs`.

The `getDOMNode` method has [been deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode)

> getDOMNode is deprecated and has been replaced with
>   React.findDOMNode().

Answer (score 0):

To expand on adeneo's answer, instead of doing `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.username)` you can simply do `this.refs.username` because the ref that is returned **is** the DOM Node.

See this link for the reference:
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#dom-node-refs